# how to pass file as argument & modify it in python script using argparse module?

Tags: python, parsing, command-line, argparse, file-handling

My requirement is to read a text file from command line interface, fetch the data in it & use it in further code.
But, I'm unable to do it.
If i use the line1, then It is throwing error1
If line 1 is commented, It is throeing error2

I also tried with args.file in line1.

Can you help me in taking the file as input and use file methods to modify it?

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("file", type=argparse.FileType('rt'))
args = parser.parse_args()
#f = open("file", "r") ---line1
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
print(lines[0].rstrip('\n'))
print(lines[1])
```

error 1:

```
py parser.py demo.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nthotapalli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\parser.py", line 6, in <module>
    f = open("file", "r")
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'file'
```

error 2:

```
py parser.py demo.txt
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\nthotapalli\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\parser.py", line 9, in <module>
    lines = file.readlines()
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'
```

Answer (score 1):

To call `readlines()` you need to have a `file like object`.

To have a `file like object` you need to call `open(<filename>)`

So in your case it would be:

```
file = open(args.file)
lines = file.readlines()
```

Or with context manager:

```
with open(args.file) as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass the path of the file as an argument and then open it, that way you can access the object's methods.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-f", "--file", help="File path", default="/tmp/file.txt")
args = parser.parse_args()

file = open(args.file, "r")
lines = file.readlines()

print(f"Number of lines: {len(lines)}")
print(f"Fist line: {lines[0]}")
```

Answer (score 0):

`args` is the Namespace produced by the parser.  You need to fetch the values from that, not use a string "file", or uninitialized variable `file`.  And 2nd be aware of what the `FileType` produces.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("file", type=argparse.FileType('rt'))
args = parser.parse_args()
```

add

```
print(args)   # to see what the parser found
file = args.file   #
```

then you can do:

```
lines = file.readlines()
file.close()
```

The problem with:

```
f = open("file", "r")
```

is you are trying open a file called "file".

With `FileType`, `args.file` will be a already opened file, which you can then read and close.  No further `open` is needed, or even possible.

Alternatively you could have defined:

```
parser.add_argument("file")
```

in which case `args.file` will a string, which you can use in the `open`

```
file = open(args.file)
```

or better yet

```
with open(args.file) as file:
     lines = file.readlines()
```

Comment: Thankyou for all, whoever answered. I tried all the ways that were listed above. But it was not working. The error is : FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'args.file'.  But there exist a file in the path.

Comment: Are you using `open('args.file')`?